# Determining SendMessageTimeout failure reason

Tags: delphi, sendmessage, getlasterror

If a SendMessageTimeout call fails (i.e., returns 0), but a subsequent GetLastError returns 0 (success), is there any way to determine why the call failed?

The code I'm using (below) works fine for dozens of our users but for two users the SendMessageTimeout fails as described in the first sentence above.

```
function TQBInfo.GetFormCellText(bTestForCaret: boolean = True): string;
const
  BUFSIZE = 4096;
  TIMEOUT_MSECS = 4000;
var
  Wnd: HWnd;
  dwResult: DWORD;
  buf: array of char;
  sLastErrorText: string;
begin
  Result := '';

  Wnd := GetEditControlWindow;          //Custom function to find the target window
  if Wnd = 0 then
    exit;

  SetLastError(0);
  FLastError_GetFormCellText := 0;      //FLastError_GetFormCellText is an object field
  SetLength(buf, BUFSIZE + 1);
  if SendMessageTimeout(Wnd, WM_GETTEXT, BUFSIZE + 1, LongInt(@buf[0]),
      SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG or SMTO_BLOCK,
      TIMEOUT_MSECS,
      dwResult) = 0 then begin                 //0 = Failed or timed out
    FLastError_GetFormCellText := GetLastError;
    //...at this point, FLastError_GetFormCellText is always 0 in the failure case I'm seeing
    if FLastError_GetFormCellText = ERROR_TIMEOUT then
      sLastErrorText := 'ERROR_TIMEOUT'
    else
      sLastErrorText := SysErrorMessage(FLastError_GetFormCellText);
...
```

Comment: Looks like you're not alone. See the first post in the community content of the documentation.

Comment: One wonders why you dynamically allocate a fixed length buffer

Comment: @Sertac - Thanks, I'll try the suggestion there to see if I can get a different failure result in terms of the system error code.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - You are correct to point that out--I think it's an artifact of a different approach used earlier.

Comment: The one user still willing to work with me on this problem just notified me that this function only fails if a Web browser is open--he has tried both Firefox and Internet Explorer. Weird, but a clue to pursue.

Comment: @Mark - I don't think that approach makes much sense. What you'll set will be probably the error code what you'll get. I would just consider the message failed, be it timeout if it makes a difference.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz - you're probably correct. But my code currently calls SetLastError(0), so initializing the error code to a different value may be interesting, just to see if Windows is changing the error code at all when SendMessageTimeout fails as it is in this case.

Comment: @Mark - While you're at it you can move SetLastError just before SendMessageTimeout, in case memory allocating for the buffer sets it to something else (VirtualAlloc, etc).,